# How to autoselect radio buttons in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form that contains several rows of radio buttons. When a button is selected in the first row (only first row), I need the subsequent rows to be auto-selected one position over (to the right) from the previous selection until end of table is reached.

Result should look like this, after clicking on "MD" in the first row:
[Desired Output](http://snag.gy/iGT9b.jpg)

[See JSFiddle Example Here](https://goo.gl/5bQGyH)

The solution should be relative-position-based if that makes any sense. The only element with consistent ID is the table ("#skuTable").

What I have so far is this (console logging to debug):

```
$("#skuTable tr").first().find("input:radio").on("click", function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    console.log($this);
    console.log($this.position());
    console.log($this.parents("tbody").children("tr:nth-child(2)").find("input:radio").first().prop('checked', true));
});
```

What that manages to do is select the first radio button on the following row. I need some help figuring out how to select the next radio button relative to the first one's position.

Comment: What do you want to do if a person selects the last element of the first row?

Comment: That shouldn't happen at all in this use-case; but if it does, it doesn't need to do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I did it:

```
var rows = $("#skuTable tr");

rows.eq(0).find("input:radio").each(function(i) {
    $(this).on("click", function() {
        for(var m = 0, n = rows.length;m < n;m++) {
            rows.eq(m).find("input:radio").eq(i + m).attr("checked", true);
        }
    });                              
});
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/Lnk9p55x/4/

Comment: If I select 4XL and then M/S in first row, the result is inconsistent.

Comment: So you're saying like unchecking the previously checked radio buttons?

Answer (score 1):

one more solution:

```
  $("#skuTable").find("input:radio").on("click", function(){
      loop = 0;
      $("input").prop("checked",false);
      index = $(this).parent().index("td");
      $.each($("table tbody tr"), function() {
          $("table tbody tr:eq("+loop+")").find("td:eq("+index+")").find("input:radio").prop('checked', true);
          index++;
          loop++;
      });
  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lnk9p55x/7/